# Use a symbolic link to redirect?

Tags: symlink, cd-command

Is it possible to set up a symbolic link such that `cd` called on the link redirects to the linked path? Kind of like this:

```
$ ln /A/B /B/C
$ cd /A/B
$ pwd
/B/C
$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using `bash`, `zsh` or any POSIX shell, then

```
cd -P
pwd -P
```

or to make it permanent.

- in `bash`: `set -P` or `set -o physical`
- in `zsh`: `set -w` or `set -o chaselinks`
- in other POSIX shells: `alias cd='cd -P'`
- in `tcsh`: `set symlinks = chase`

But the effect you're seeing is created by the shell, not by the link itself.  So the answer to your actual question is "no".